# Store string as jsonb column with npgsql

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, jsonb, npgsql

I have the following model

```
public class Guardian
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set ;}
        public string address { get; set; }

        public string Questions;

        public IList<Urgency> Urgencies { get; set; } = new List<Urgency>();
    }
```

And this line of code on my AppDbContext: DbContext

```
builder.Entity<Guardian>().Property(d => d.Questions).HasColumnType(NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb);
```

I want the Questions string field to be stored as JsonB type on the postgreSQL database. I get this error:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType' to 'string'
```

Which totally makes sense, but don't know how should i approach it, i have done research but nothing seems to target my particular situation. I'd truly appreciate some advice.

Comment: Quick thing to try: According to the [docs](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=fluent-api%2Cpoco), it should be `HasColumnType("jsonb")`.

Comment: @NateBarbettini thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

`HasColumnType` - which is a general EF Core method - accepts a database type name is a string (e.g. the string `jsonb`), and not the Npgsql-specific `NpgsqlDbType.Enum`. You should simply change your code as follows:

```cs
builder.Entity<Guardian>().Property(d => d.Questions).HasColumnType("jsonb");
```

[See the Npgsql EF Core provider docs](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=fluent-api%2Cpoco) for this and other info on JSON mapping.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using `DataAnnotation`:

```
[Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
public string Questions { get; set; }
```